# Make Snackbar push view upwards

Tags: android, snackbar

Is there a way to make the snackbar push the view upwards when it is shown?

[image: snackbar]

Currently, when the snackbar is shown, it overlays the view below so it looks like half the button is cut off but I want it to almost "adjustPan" similar to the way that the softkeyboard works when it is shown on the screen.

Does anyone know of any tricks to achieve this?

Answer (score 24):

Put your view inside a android.support.design.CoordinatorLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.FloatingActionButtonBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The important part here is app:layout_behavior attribute. Here is implementing class:

```
public class FloatingActionButtonBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    public FloatingActionButtonBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {

        return dependency instanceof SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {

        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then when you show the snackbar pass the reference to the CoordinatorLayout:

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinator = findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
Snackbar.make(coordinator, textResId, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction(R.string.accept_ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        })
        .setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .show();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm using a viewGroup (LinearLayout) inside my coordinatorlayout instead of a view. Is there anyway to use viewgroup with your code? I tried it with the linearLayout but it gives me an error saying: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: Just add a coordinatorlayout at bottom.

Comment: The behavior class then must extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<LinearLayout>

Comment: I used this solution to push a floatinactionbutton (3rd party lib). Hope you found the solution.

Comment: I used this solution to push my relativeLayout, works like a charm :) @Simon did you forget to change FloatingActionButton to LinearLayout also in both the overriden methods?

Comment: Please have a look at this question, maybe it will give you a better idea of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528081/how-do-i-push-an-existing-view-up-when-snackbar-is-displayed

Comment: I just want to point out that even though the empty constructor looks useless, if you don't declare it you'll get an exception during layout preview in the design view.

Comment: With this solution, if you are using swipe to dismiss snackbar feature, you layout will stay on new position. To return to old position you may use         `snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                yourLayout.setTranslationY(0.0f);
            }
        });`

Comment: I would like to add, that you need to create your Custom Bahavior. So, in general, it looks like CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<T> where T - the child view. (The view which have to be moved in case of snackbar or other dependency)

Comment: Bummer, not working for me with a LinearLayout, snackbar doesn't even appear

Comment: thanks for this. actually you could make it more generic by extending `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>` to make it work with any View. worked out for me.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: If all you want is to push the View upwards when the Snackbar shows up, just add the following line to your View. No need to define `FloatingActionButtonBehavior` anymore.

```
app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
```

Long Answer: `FloatingActionButtonBehavior` described in the accepted answer certainly gets the job done.

One thing I noticed is that, if I have a `CoordinatorLayout` and a real `FloatingActionButton` with no `FloatingActionButtonBehavior`, then the FAB feels slightly "bouncy" when the Snackbar shows up. But if I use something else, such as a `ConstraintLayout` along with `FloatingActionButtonBehavior`, then the "bouncy" feeling is just not there; the View above the Snackbar just shows up with enough space at the bottom for the Snackbar, and the Snackbar gradually fills the space. It's rather subtle, and I'm sure most people don't even notice it nor care about it.

This is when the Snackbar starts to show up. Notice that its size is slightly smaller than its full size.

[image]

And a fraction of a second later, the Snackbar "expands" to its full size.

[image]

This is what contributes to the "bouncy" feeling; FAB's location is based on the Snackbar's current size, not the Snackbar's fully shown size.

To replicate this behavior, just let `FloatingActionButtonBehavior` know where to anchor FAB, instead of calculating the Y coordinate yourself. Better yet, refer to "Short Answer".

```
/*
Replicate real FAB's behavior. Code shamelessly stolen from
com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java
*/
class FloatingActionButtonBehavior(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>() {
    override fun onAttachedToLayoutParams(params: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
        super.onAttachedToLayoutParams(params)

        if (params.dodgeInsetEdges == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
            params.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` solution actually works and does not feel like a hack. One must just place it in the uppermost layout view, that is for example in the `activity_main.xml` Coordinator Layout for one-activity-multiple-fragments apps.

Answer (score 2):

He is SourceRebeles solution using generics in Kotlin.

```
typealias T = View

class FloatingActionButtonBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<T>() {

    override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: T, dependency: View): Boolean {

        return dependency is SnackbarLayout
    }

    override fun onDependentViewChanged(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: T, dependency: View): Boolean {

        val translationY = Math.min(0.0f, (dependency.translationY - dependency.height).toFloat())
        child.translationY = translationY
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Snackbar will find closest `CoordinatorLayout` as `parentView`;

```
 findViewById(R.id.tv_main).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.tv_main), "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            toolbar.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:text="s"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main"
            android:background="#4b14b1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```