# Snackbar overlaps view instead moving it up; how can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-view

I have a Coordinator Layout like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_subreddit_selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/addFabMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in my code, I have a snackbar like so:

```
 Snackbar.make(getView().findViewById(R.id.addFabMenu),
            R.string.no_entered_subreddit_name, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

And here is what I what:

[image]

I've tried copying the code from the example activity exactly but it still does not work like the example activity.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709953/make-snackbar-push-view-upwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by creating a Coordinator behaviour like so:

```
public class MoveUpwardBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {
    private static final boolean SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED;

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }

    static {
        SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11;
    }
}
```

And extended my view class, applying the behaviour to it

```
@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(MoveUpwardBehavior.class)
public class MoveUpwardsFloatingMenu extends FloatingActionMenu {
    public MoveUpwardsFloatingMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MoveUpwardsFloatingMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MoveUpwardsFloatingMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard `FloatingActionButton` from the support library

Instead of:

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/addFabMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
```

Use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/addFabMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
```

Comment: The clans FAB offers some features I need like menu etc. Does view-moving only work with the standard FAB?

Answer (score 0):

> CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior annotation was deprecated from API
> level 27.1.0.

To add a Behavior to your custom View, you just need to implement **CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior** interface to return the default behavior or using  **layout_behavior attribute** that is present will override the AttachedBehavior.

Here you can see an example:

```
class MoveUpwardBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>() {
    
        override fun layoutDependsOn(
            parent: CoordinatorLayout,
            child: View,
            dependency: View): Boolean = dependency is SnackbarLayout
    
        override fun onDependentViewChanged(
            parent: CoordinatorLayout,
            child: View,
            dependency: View
        ): Boolean {
            child.translationY = min(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE, dependency.translationY - dependency.height)
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onDependentViewRemoved(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: View, dependency: View) {
            super.onDependentViewRemoved(parent, child, dependency)
            child.translationY = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE
        }
    
    
        companion object {
    
            private const val DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 0f
    
        }
    }



    class ExampleComponentView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior {
    
    .....
    
    override fun getBehavior(): CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<*> =
            MoveUpwardBehavior()
    }
```